# SCP only latest file

Tags: networking, bash, ssh

I want to download only the latest file using SCP from a remote folder.  The files are in format `raw_201712282131.ubx` where the number is the date of file.

If I do this command in SSH I can get the latest file name:

```
find -name '*.ubx' | sort -V | tail -1
```

How to download only the latest file using SCP?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this and see if it works. It works fine for me on macOS going to  various Linux (CentOS, Ubuntu, etc…) servers:

```
RECENT=$(ssh someone@example.com ls -lrt /remote/path/ | awk '/.ubx/ { f=$NF }; END { print f }');
scp someone@example.com:/remote/path/${RECENT} /local/path/${RECENT};
```

The first line gets the most recent file with the extension of `.ubx` and assigns it to the `$RECENT` variable.

The next line then just runs the SCP command itself. You can make it into a “one-liner” by just combining both lines into one like this:

```
RECENT=$(ssh someone@example.com ls -lrt /remote/path/ | awk '/.ubx/ { f=$NF }; END { print f }'); scp someone@example.com:/remote/path/${RECENT} /local/path/${RECENT};
```

And—of course—you could just set variables for the user, hostname, `/remote/path/` and `/local/path/` and just place it in a Bash script file to run it with one command like `get_latest_ubx.sh` so you don’t have to deal with typing in a command like that each time you need to use it.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Assign the variables.
USER='someone';
HOST='example.com';
LOCAL_PATH='/local/path/';
REMOTE_PATH='/remote/path/';

# Get the most recent `.ubx` file and assign it to `RECENT`.
RECENT=$(ssh ${USER}@${HOST} ls -lrt ${REMOTE_PATH} | awk '/.ubx/ { f=$NF }; END { print f }');

# Run the actual SCP command.
scp ${USER}@${HOST}:${REMOTE_PATH}${RECENT} ${LOCAL_PATH}${RECENT};
```

Comment: Turns out I didnt need to dl the latest file changed my mind.